# Differential of a matrix term wrt a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, maximum-likelihood

Say we have a term as $P = XCX^t-XB-B^tX^t+C$ where all three matrices $X, C, B$ are square $n\times n$ matrices. Matrix $C$ is symmetric and $X,B$ are *asymmetric* with $X$ having zero as diagonal values (would have $n^2-n$ elements at max). $B, C$ are known and $X$ is the unknown. How can we compute the derivative of $PP^t$ with respect to matrix $X$?

PS. This is a MLE derivation and I want to solve for matrix $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\sym#1{\operatorname{sym}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Define the function
$$\eqalign{
\sym A = \tfrac 12\LR{A+A^T} \\
}$$
Then the differential of $P$ is
$$\eqalign{
P &= XCX^T - XB - B^TX^T + C \\
dP &= 2\,\sym{dX\,\CLR{CX^T-B}} \\
}$$
and the differential of the product in question is
$$\eqalign{
M &= PP^T \\
dM &= 2\,\sym{dP\,P^T} \\
 &= 4\,\sym{\sym{dX\,\CLR{CX^T-B}}\,P^T} \\
}$$
If you want the **derivative**, just substitute $H\to dX$ as the direction of interest.

If you want the **gradient**, then you have a problem. A matrix-by-matrix gradient is a fourth order tensor and cannot be expressed using standard matrix notation.

However, since the **componentwise gradient** of a matrix with respect to itself is
$$\eqalign{
\grad{X}{X_{ij}} &= E_{ij} \qquad \big\{{\rm single\,entry\;matrix}\big\}\qquad \\
}$$
the componentwise gradient of your product can be written as
$$\eqalign{
\grad{(PP^T)}{X_{ij}} &= 4\,\sym{\sym{E_{ij}\CLR{CX^T-B}}\,P^T}
\quad
\\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

@greg's answer is much more succinct, but if you want gore:

Let $\phi(X) = X C X^T -XB-B^TX^T+C$, then by examining $\phi(X+H)-\phi(X)$ and taking the linear part we get $D \phi(X) H = HCX^T + XCH^T -HB-B^TH^T$.

Similarly for $\eta(X) = X X^T$ we have $D \eta(X)H = H X^T+X H^T$.

The chain rule gives
$D \eta \circ \phi (X) H = D \eta(\phi(X)) D \phi(X)H = (D \phi(X)H) \phi(X)^T + \phi(X) (D \phi(X)H)^T$.
Expanding
$D \eta \circ \phi (X) H = ( H X^T+X H^T) ( X C X^T -XB-B^TX^T+C) + (X C X^T -XB-B^TX^T+C) ( H X^T+X H^T)$.